# Misleading instructions in CiviEvent registration template for multiple participants

Tags: civievent, online-registration

In Civi 5.26.1, I've just had a user tell me that a registration page doesn't work because there is no 'Continue' button.

Indeed, although the on-page instructions state "If you are registering additional people, you will be able to enter their registration information after you complete this page and click Continue", the only button available says 'Review you registration'.

Suggest that the relevant string in Register.tpl is amended to 'If you are registering additional people, you will be able to enter their information after you complete this page and click Review Registration'

Answer (score 3):

This is a great catch Bryan.  The wording changed in CiviCRM 5.25 (May 2020), but they missed this.  I just [opened a ticket](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/-/issues/38) and [wrote a patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17695) to address this.  The fix is in Civi 5.29+ (September 2020).  Thanks again not just for noticing, but for reporting this.